# When creating a vector of objects, how to pass arguments to Default or Copy Constructor to initialize values?

Tags: c++, c++11

For a program I'm writing for a project in my C++ class, one of the requirements is to use constructors to initialize data members in objects.

We also have to read from binary files.

The method I chose to accomplish this was:

```
// Loads invmast.dat or creates one if none exists
fstream invFile;
invFile.open("invmast.dat", std::fstream::in);
if (!invFile)
{
    cout << "File invmast.dat not found, creating a new one." << endl;
    invFile.open("invmast.dat", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app | std::fstream::binary);
    if (!invFile)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to create or open file invmast.dat; exiting." << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
cout << "File invmast.dat opened successfully." << endl;

vector <InventoryItem> invMast;
//vector <InventoryItem>::iterator invMastIterator;

InventoryItem invLoader;

while ( invFile && !invFile.eof())
{
    invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&invLoader), sizeof(invLoader));
    invMast.insert(invMast.begin(), invLoader);      
}
```

I'd prefer to create a vector of objects and pass the arguments to the copy or default constructor, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Is there a way, or do I need to rethink my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to construct the fstream with the file name and the options (and include ios_base:binary): std::fstream invFile("invmast.dat", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base:binary);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were simply constructing an element, you could use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to construct it directly in the `vector`:

```
invMast.emplace_back(some, constructor, parameters);
```

But here, since you’re initialising the `InventoryItem` from raw bytes, you probably just want to construct an object and move it into the vector:

```
invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&invMast.back()), sizeof(invLoader));
invMast.push_back(std::move(invLoader));
```

Or default-construct an element and then fill it:

```
invMast.emplace_back();
invFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&invMast.back()), sizeof(InventoryItem));
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  It almost seems like it might be easier to use emplace_back and rewrite how I am bringing in the data from the file.  Unfortunately I have to fulfill the requirement of using a constructor to initialize the data members for all my classes -- so filling the element after constructors won't work.

Comment: You could provide an argument of std::istream& to the constructor.