# vector of objects - how to send a parameter to the constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, constructor

Let us say I have the following code:

```
struct obj{
    int v;
    obj(int i = 1){
        v = i;
    }
};

int main(){
    vector<obj> v1(10);    // (1)
    vector<obj> v2(15);    // (2)
}
```

Per above:

Number (1) creates a vector that has 10 instances of **`obj`** with default **`v=1`**.
Number (2) how to send **15** as a parameter to **`obj`** so **`v=15`**???

I searched the net and found this **[article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623497/when-creating-a-vector-of-objects-how-to-pass-arguments-to-default-or-copy-cons?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)** on this site, but it seems about more advanced things and as a novice I did not get it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Do you want make *one* `obj` that contains 15, or a vector of some number of them, each containing 15?

Comment: 10 objects with 15 as construction value? also what if I have two or more parameters?

Comment: Why down vote. Please tell the reason so I can learn. This is my 1st question ever.

Comment: Vote downs should be accompanied with a comment explaining why the vote down was cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vector<obj> v1(10);     // creates a vector of 10 obj, each initialized 
                        // with the default value 1

vector<obj> v2(10, 15); // creates a vector of 10 obj, each initialized 
                        // with the value 15
```

If you want to pass more than one argument to the constructors :

```
vector<obj> v3(10, obj(15, x, y)); // creates a vector of 10 obj, each 
                                   // initialized with (15, x, y)
```

You would of course have to provide a constructor that takes three arguments for that to work.

Comment: Note that `vector<obj> v2(10, 15);` is the same as `vector<obj> v2(10, obj(15));` The second parameter of this `vector` constructor is a `const T& value`, where each element gets copy-constructed with `value` as its input.  Passing `15` by itself creates an implicit temporary `obj` to pass to `value`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
vector<obj> v3 (10,15);
```

10 is number of objects.
15 is the parameter to the constructor.

for multiple parameters, you can send multiple values as a list as follows:

```
vector<obj> v3 (10, {15,25} );
```

**`{15,25}`**. This is called an initializer list.

An alternative would be:

```
vector<obj> v3(10, obj(15,25));
```

See *Baum*'s note. It is a good reference.